# have to wait 15 minute ubuntu zfs 16.04 fully boot

Tags: 16.04, root, zfs

i have folow guide install zfs raidz2
https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/wiki/Ubuntu-16.04-Root-on-ZFS.

the problem is every boot i have to wait nearly 15 minutes until fully boot.
any help?

Comment: Look at the results of both `journalctl -b` and `dmesg --kernel --ctime --userspace --decode` and look for large inter-message intervals.

Comment: its start after bios , then it goes to blank sreen, after 15++minutes, then it booted flawlessly. i dont know it seem kind a hhd problem but no sign hhd led up.